# Debounced function never fires in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have installed this Vue package:

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/debounce
```

I need it to debounce the event handler that fires when the window is resized:

```
    created() {
        window.addEventListener("resize", this.handleResize);
    },

    destroyed() {
        window.removeEventListener("resize", this.handleResize);
    },

    methods : {
        handleResize : function() {
            debounce(function (e) {
                let date = new Date();
                let timestamp = date. getTime();
                console.log(timestamp);
            }, 1000, true)
        },
    }
```

The `console.log` never happens when I resize the window. When I remove the debounce bit and just leave the following, then it works:

```
        handleResize : function() {
            let date = new Date();
            let timestamp = date. getTime();
            console.log(timestamp);
        },
```

How do I get this to work?

Comment: `devounce` should return a new function. You're never invoking or returning that function, so it will never execute. Also, you should have a *single* debounced function right now you're running *debounce* every time `handleResize` is called which produces many deounced funnctions. So, either `handleResize: debounce(function() { /*... */ })` or `window.addEventListener("resize", debounce(this.handleResize))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now you `this.handleResize` is just a function to create a debounce function so when the window resize you just create a new debounce function.

You code should be something like:

```js
    created() {
        this.handleResize = debounce(function (e) {
            let date = new Date();
            let timestamp = date. getTime();
            console.log(timestamp);
        }, 1000, true)

        window.addEventListener("resize", this.handleResize);
    },

    destroyed() {
        window.removeEventListener("resize", this.handleResize);
    }
```

or

```js
    data: () => ({
        handleResize: debounce(function (e) {
            let date = new Date();
            let timestamp = date. getTime();
            console.log(timestamp);
        }, 1000, true)
    })
    created() {
        window.addEventListener("resize", this.handleResize);
    },

    destroyed() {
        window.removeEventListener("resize", this.handleResize);
    }
```